# Error in creating a virtual machine in using vagrant

Tags: azure, vagrant

I want to create a virtual machine in Azure using Vagrant. I follow this link [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/azure-devops-vagrant-jo%C3%A3o-pedro-soares/)
I have obtained successfully the credentials of azure and here is my vagrantFile:

```html
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
  # vi: set ft=ruby :

  # All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
  #Ponemos el plugin que hemos instalado antes y que se explica durante el tutorial
  require "vagrant-azure"
  # configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
  # backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
  # you're doing.
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  #Aqui ponemos el nuestro box al lugar del box por defecto.
  # config.vm.box = "base"
  config.vm.box = "azure"
  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "/home/elda/.ssh/id_rsa"
  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
  #   # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
  #   vb.memory = "1024"
  # end
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.
  # Configuramos el niuestro proveedor azure
  config.vm.provider "azure" do |az, override|
  # Los param del VM 
    #az.vm_name = 'pgtic_test2'
    #az.vm_size = 'Standard_B1s'
    #az.vm_image_urn = 'Canonical:UbuntuServer:16.04-LTS:latest'
    #az.resource_group_name = 'vagrant'
  # Aqui usamos el informacion obtenido del servicio principal Azure AD 
 # Tweak to bypass Azure Box not found 
    az.tenant_id = ".........."
    az.client_id = "........."
    az.client_secret = ".........."
    az.subscription_id = "............."
  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL
end
 config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo Hello, World"
 end
```

All the plugins are installed, but the problem is that when I try to `vagrant up` the machine it gives me an error, for which I cannot find a response:

```html
 Bringing machine 'default' up with 'azure' provider...
==> default: Launching an instance with the following settings...
==> default:  -- Management Endpoint: https://management.azure.com
==> default:  -- Subscription Id: ebf53860-e727-4003-90bc-3d099632c913
==> default:  -- Resource Group Name: red-darkness-38
==> default:  -- Location: westus
==> default:  -- Admin Username: vagrant
==> default:  -- VM Name: polished-voice-23
==> default:  -- VM Storage Account Type: Premium_LRS
==> default:  -- VM Size: Small
==> default:  -- Image URN: canonical:ubuntuserver:16.04.0-LTS:latest
==> default:  -- DNS Label Prefix: polished-voice-23
/home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/azure_mgmt_compute-0.10.0/lib/generated/azure_mgmt_compute/virtual_machine_images.rb:218:in `block in list_async': { (MsRestAzure::AzureOperationError)
  "message": "MsRestAzure::AzureOperationError: AuthorizationFailed: The client '6939d76b-a697-42d0-a52f-1af3c8412d51' with object id '6939d76b-a697-42d0-a52f-1af3c8412d51' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/locations/publishers/artifacttypes/offers/skus/versions/read' over scope '/subscriptions/ebf53860-e727-4003-90bc-3d099632c913'.",
  "request": {
    "base_uri": "https://management.azure.com",
    "path_template": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/{location}/publishers/{publisherName}/artifacttypes/vmimage/offers/{offer}/skus/{skus}/versions",
    "method": "get",
    "path_params": {
      "location": "westus",
      "publisherName": "canonical",
      "offer": "ubuntuserver",
      "skus": "16.04.0-LTS",
      "subscriptionId": "ebf53860-e727-4003-90bc-3d099632c913"
    },
    "skip_encoding_path_params": null,
    "query_params": {
      "$filter": null,
      "$top": null,
      "$orderby": null,
      "api-version": "2016-04-30-preview"
    },
    "skip_encoding_query_params": null,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "accept-language": "en-US",
      "x-ms-client-request-id": "da80d2da-c90b-4f3e-8085-8545dfe9928c"
    },
    "body": null,
    "middlewares": [
      [
        "MsRest::RetryPolicyMiddleware",
        {
          "times": 3,
          "retry": 0.02
        }
      ],
      [
        "cookie_jar"
      ]
    ],
    "log": null
  },
  "response": {
    "body": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"AuthorizationFailed\",\"message\":\"The client '6939d76b-a697-42d0-a52f-1af3c8412d51' with object id '6939d76b-a697-42d0-a52f-1af3c8412d51' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/locations/publishers/artifacttypes/offers/skus/versions/read' over scope '/subscriptions/ebf53860-e727-4003-90bc-3d099632c913'.\"}}",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "expires": "-1",
      "x-ms-failure-cause": "gateway",
      "x-ms-request-id": "d2824106-2381-455d-89a8-7b20e84539a3",
      "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "d2824106-2381-455d-89a8-7b20e84539a3",
      "x-ms-routing-request-id": "FRANCESOUTH:20180419T225147Z:d2824106-2381-455d-89a8-7b20e84539a3",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
      "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
      "date": "Thu, 19 Apr 2018 22:51:47 GMT",
      "connection": "close",
      "content-length": "349"
    },
    "status": 403
  }
}
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/promise.rb:501:in `block in on_fulfill'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:24:in `block in execute'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization/mri_lockable_object.rb:38:in `block in synchronize'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization/mri_lockable_object.rb:38:in `synchronize'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/synchronization/mri_lockable_object.rb:38:in `synchronize'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/safe_task_executor.rb:19:in `execute'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/promise.rb:531:in `block in realize'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:348:in `run_task'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:337:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `loop'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:320:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `catch'
 from /home/elda/.vagrant.d/gems/2.4.3/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in `block in create_worker'
```

It seems that there are no syntax errors or something missing.
If somebody has had the same problem can you please share with me the solution?
I have owner permissions :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AExOO.png)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same issue when creating an object in the subscription. Your account needs the proper permissions to create the object.

**From Microsoft: (Edited)**

Due to the error shown, it seems is the most probable cause.

The service principal you are using doesn't have rights within that tenant.

Tenants have subscriptions and service principals belong to tenants. Azure resource manager also exposes role based authorization for a given principal, which would give it rights on Azure resources. It appears the service principal doesn't have rights to read from that subscription.

Comment: I have owner permission  I have edited my uestion with the image from my account permissions.

Comment: Hi! Have a look to this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure/issues/164)



It redirects to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: I have already done all of this. And it still seems to output the same error.

Comment: So I have previously created this SErvide Principa, obtained teh credentials there and putting them inside vagrant file.